# How can I call every method in a class on the same thread without using a sync block for every invocation?

Tags: swift

I have a class named MyClass.
What I want to do is make sure that every time one of its methods is invoked that the method always gets called on the same queue.

I'm trying to ensure that every method I call in MyClass gets called on the same queue. This is because MyClass acts as an access point to the data that drives my application. Any time any part of the app needs to get or set the single source of truth it goes through this class. I want to safely prevent any concurrency issues accessing or modifying the source of truth.

I can do this by wrapping each invocation in async block.
I'm looking for a more elegant and less 'bulky' way to achieve this.

My question is, how can I achieve this without having to wrap every single method call in a block?

```
class MyClass {
    static let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "myqueue",
                                     attributes: .concurrent)

    func functionSet1(value: String) {
    }

    func functionGet1() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func functionSet2(value: String) {
    }

    func functionGet2() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}

class Invoker {
    let invokee: MyClass = MyClass()
    
    func call1() {
        MyClass.queue.sync {
            invokee.functionGet1()
        }
    }

    func call2() {
        MyClass.queue.sync {
            invokee.functionGet2()
        }
    }

    func call3() {
        MyClass.queue.sync {
            invokee.functionSet1(value: "value")
        }
    }

    func call1() {
        MyClass.queue.sync {
            invokee.functionSet1(value: "value")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you hadn't chosen a concurrent queue, I might have proposed an actor, which does something analogous to a serial queue. But perhaps we can ask why you want to do this and perhaps we can offer solutions to the broader question.

Comment: I updated my question with more details about what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: Thanks for clarification. But I’m afraid that a concurrent queue won’t solve that concern. A serial queue would. Or (the vastly overrated) reader-writer pattern. But this is precisely the problem that actors were designed to solve. See [Protect mutable state with Swift actors](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10133). If this is your first time playing with Swift concurrency, it may be overwhelming, but it’s worth getting your arms around this.

Comment: Yeah I had tried reader writer pattern using a barrier. I think I should, as you suggest, embrace the future and get to work learning actors. Thanks for the advice and steering me in the right direction. Happy to accept your solution to this problem

Comment: Looks like vadian [has captured](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77501635/1271826) the gist of what I was saying, so feel free to accept that…

Comment: At the risk of splitting hairs, it should be noted that neither the properly implemented GCD approach nor Swift actors technically guarantee that it is “on the same thread”. Only that you aren’t mutating from different threads at the same time (which is all that we’re concerned about).

Comment: Is there a good reason for the two classes? It seems like it would be simpler to just have one class and eliminate `Invoker`.

Comment: Agreed. It is ill-advised to add another tightly-coupled type to provide a thread-safe interface to an object that is, itself, not thread-safe. Obviously, if we had control over the source code for the existing type, we would always just make it thread-safe rather than introducing a new, hopelessly entangled, type into the mix. (FWIW, sometimes the method-by-method synchronization is the wrong idea anyway. Sometimes we need synchronization at a higher level of abstraction. It varies case-by-case.)

Comment: @HangarRash in my case you could consider MyClass my "DataBase Layer" and Invoker as the rest of the app. My app is a bit weird in that it doesnt use a database at all but uses an in memory JSON file that I query via MyClass. (Some legacy app I'm trying to tame)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Rob said that's a great example to use an `actor`.
Although the functions are marked as `async` the execution takes place in order on the thread of the actor which *acts* as a serial queue. A concurrent queue contradicts your needs anyway.

```
actor MyActor {
    func functionSet1(value: String) {
        print("functionSet1", value)
    }
    func functionGet1() -> Bool {
        print("functionGet1")
        return true
    }
    func functionSet2(value: String) {
        print("functionSet2", value)
    }
    func functionGet2() -> Bool {
        print("functionGet2")
        return true
    }
}

class Invoker {
    let invokee = MyActor()
    
    func call1() async  {
        await invokee.functionGet1()
    }
    func call2() async {
        await invokee.functionGet2()
    }
    func call3() async {
        await invokee.functionSet1(value: "value1")
    }
    func call4() async {
        await invokee.functionSet2(value: "value2")
    }
}

Task {
    let invoker = Invoker()
    await invoker.call1()
    await invoker.call2()
    await invoker.call3()
    await invoker.call4()
}
```